# Arquivo amr convertido de wav diferente do original

Tags: android

Estou convertendo um arquivo wav para amr utilizando a biblioteca amrInputStream, mas o arquivo original Wav tem 15s 387ms de duração com o tamanho de 1.3Mb e o arquivo gerado AMR tem 133kb mas fica com 1m 25s de duração, além de ficar lento e distorcido na reprodução. O que estou fazendo errado?
Aqui está o codigo da classe AmrInputStream

```
package android.media;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * AmrInputStream
 * @hide
 */
public final class AmrInputStream extends InputStream
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("media_jni");
    }

    private final static String TAG = "AmrInputStream";

    // frame is 20 msec at 8.000 khz
    private final static int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 8000 * 20 / 1000;

    // pcm input stream
    private InputStream mInputStream;

    // native handle
    private long mGae;

    // result amr stream
    private final byte[] mBuf = new byte[SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * 2];
    private int mBufIn = 0;
    private int mBufOut = 0;

    // helper for bytewise read()
    private byte[] mOneByte = new byte[1];

    /**
     * Create a new AmrInputStream, which converts 16 bit PCM to AMR
     * @param inputStream InputStream containing 16 bit PCM.
     */
    public AmrInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        mInputStream = inputStream;
        mGae = GsmAmrEncoderNew();
        GsmAmrEncoderInitialize(mGae);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int rtn = read(mOneByte, 0, 1);
        return rtn == 1 ? (0xff & mOneByte[0]) : -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        return read(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        if (mGae == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("not open");

        // local buffer of amr encoded audio empty
        if (mBufOut >= mBufIn) {
            // reset the buffer
            mBufOut = 0;
            mBufIn = 0;

            // fetch a 20 msec frame of pcm
            for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * 2; ) {
                int n = mInputStream.read(mBuf, i, SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * 2 - i);
                if (n == -1) return -1;
                i += n;
            }

            // encode it
            mBufIn = GsmAmrEncoderEncode(mGae, mBuf, 0, mBuf, 0);
        }

        // return encoded audio to user
        if (length > mBufIn - mBufOut) length = mBufIn - mBufOut;
        System.arraycopy(mBuf, mBufOut, b, offset, length);
        mBufOut += length;

        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (mInputStream != null) mInputStream.close();
        } finally {
            mInputStream = null;
            try {
                if (mGae != 0) GsmAmrEncoderCleanup(mGae);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (mGae != 0) GsmAmrEncoderDelete(mGae);
                } finally {
                    mGae = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        if (mGae != 0) {
            close();
            throw new IllegalStateException("someone forgot to close AmrInputStream");
        }
    }

    //
    // AudioRecord JNI interface
    //
    private static native long GsmAmrEncoderNew();
    private static native void GsmAmrEncoderInitialize(long gae);
    private static native int GsmAmrEncoderEncode(long gae,
                                                  byte[] pcm, int pcmOffset, byte[] amr, int amrOffset) throws IOException;
    private static native void GsmAmrEncoderCleanup(long gae);
    private static native void GsmAmrEncoderDelete(long gae);

}
```

Aqui está o codigo da classe Recorder que uso para gravar o audio do microfone, gerar o aquivo Wav e converter em AMR

```
package iupi.com.br.calls;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

import android.util.Log;

import android.media.AmrInputStream;

/**
 * Created by Bernardo on 29/06/2015.
 */
public class Recorder {

    //Begin private fields for this class
    private AudioRecord recorder;

    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = "Audio";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_ENCODED_FILE_EXT = ".amr";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "files";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.3gp";
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS_INT = 1;

    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private int bufferSize = 200000;
    short[] buffer;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private String path;

    //Constructor
    public Recorder(String path)
    {
           int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
        this.path = path;

        System.out.println("BUFFER SIZE VALUE IS " + bufferSize);

        int buffercount = 4088 / bufferSize;
        if (buffercount < 1)
            buffercount = 1;
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, 44100);

        //recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        //recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);


    }

    public void start() throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {

        buffer = new short[4088];

        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        Log.i("SmartMontor","Parando a gravacao do audio");
        stopRecording();
    }

    public boolean isRecording()
    {
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    private void stopRecording() {
        // stops the recording activity

        if (null != recorder) {
            isRecording = false;

            recorder.stop();


            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;}
        // copy the recorded file to original copy & delete the recorded copy
        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename()+AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT);
        deleteTempFile();
        convertWaveToAmr(getFilename()+AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT);
    } // stores the file into the SDCARD
    private String getFilename() {
        System.out.println("---3---");
        //String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(path, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
    }

    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());
        Log.i("SmartMontor","Deletando o arquivo temporario");

        file.delete();
    }


    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
        System.out.println("---8---");
        Log.i("SmartMontor", "Copiando o arquivo Wav na pasta");
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = RECORDER_CHANNELS_INT;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            //Controller.doDoc("File size: " + totalDataLen, 4);

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);
            byte[] bytes2 = new byte[buffer.length * 2];
            ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                    .asShortBuffer().put(buffer);
            while (in.read(bytes2) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes2);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // stores the file into the SDCARD
    private String getTempFilename() {
        // Creates the temp file to store buffer
        System.out.println("---4-1--");
        //String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        System.out.println("---4-2--");
        File file = new File(path, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
        System.out.println("---4-3--");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(path, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
        System.out.println("---4-4--");

        if (tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();
        System.out.println("---4-5--");
        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }
    private void writeAudioDataToFile() {

        // Write the output audio in byte
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

        String filename = getTempFilename();
        //
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        //
        try {
            //
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            //
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;


        // if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {
            // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
            recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // read = recorder.read(data, 0, 6144);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    // // writes the data to file from buffer
                    // // stores the voice buffer

                    // short[] shorts = new short[bytes.length/2];
                    // to turn bytes to shorts as either big endian or little
                    // endian.
                    // ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);

                    // to turn shorts back to bytes.
                    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[buffer.length * 2];
                    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                            .asShortBuffer().put(buffer);

                    os.write(bytes2);
                    //  ServerInteractor.SendAudio(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                                     long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("---9---");
        byte[] header = new byte[4088];

        header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1; // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) RECORDER_CHANNELS_INT;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (RECORDER_CHANNELS_INT * RECORDER_BPP / 8); // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 4088);
    }




    public void convertWaveToAmr(String wavFilename)
    {
        Log.i("SmartMonitor","Convertendo o arquivo para AMR");
        AmrInputStream aStream = null ;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            inStream = new FileInputStream(wavFilename);
            aStream= new AmrInputStream(inStream);
            File file = new File(getFilename()+AUDIO_ENCODED_FILE_EXT);
            file.createNewFile();
            out= new FileOutputStream(file);

            // #!AMR\n
            out.write(0x23);
            out.write(0x21);
            out.write(0x41);
            out.write(0x4D);
            out.write(0x52);
            out.write(0x0A);

            byte[] x = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len=aStream.read(x)) > 0) {
                out.write(x,0,len);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("SmartMonitor","Erro FileNotFoundException "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SmartMonitor","Erro IOException "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                out.close();
                aStream.close();
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SmartMonitor","Erro IOException 2 "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está a amostra do audio original
[Audio Wav](https://soundcloud.com/la-rcio-bernardo/audio)
E o audio apos ser convertido
[Audio AMR](https://soundcloud.com/la-rcio-bernardo/audio-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Seu problema é o `sample rate`, você esta gerando o áudio em `44100hz` e gravando em `8000hz`.

você precisa decidir e escolher qual deles utilizar, se estiver trabalhando só com voz pode ser considerado um desperdício de recursos trabalhar a 44100hz já que a voz humana pode chegar até [3400Hz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voz_humana) a faixa de espectro de um sample rate a 8000hz é mais que suficiente para atender estas necessidades.

Provando que os audios estão em sample rate diferente só com as informações passadas por você:

Multiplicando 8000hz por 1m e 25s

```
8000*85

ans =

      680000
```

Multiplicando 44100 por 15 segundos arredondando para 4 milisegundos

```
44100*15.4

ans =

      679140
```

O resultado de ambos é quase o mesmo número de samples!

Meu conselho é alterar seu wav para gravar em 8000hz linha:

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
```

E tbm a linha:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, 8000);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas após a alteração sugerida os áudios ficaram com quase o mesmo tempo mas a reprodução está muito rápida. O resultado pode ser visto (https://soundcloud.com/la-rcio-bernardo/sets/teste-amrinputstream).

Comment: Na classe Recorder somente em 44100 é que o wav fica com a reprodução normal, já o amr não fica, tentei também trocar na classe AmrInputStream o campo  private final static int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 8000 * 20 / 1000; por  private final static int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 44100 * 20 / 1000, mas também não funcionou, desculpe-me a ignorância, mas não entendo de conversão de arquivos de áudio, estou implementando por meu software funcionará como backup automático de chamadas.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 44100 ? Seu problema continua sendo o frame rate ...